# Unable to update the box's right parameter to point the current bar

Tags: pine-script

I expect the zone to be drawn toward the current bar, just like in the pictures below. Let me explain the issue. I'm adding the new box to the array and at that point the current bar is the next bar after the box gets created and whenever new bars appear, it doesn't update the `right` direction of the box.

I tried to update the box in the loop by adding: `box.set_bottom(array.get(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), time)`, but nothing really happened. Actually everything disappeared, which means it's incorrect.

## Current behavior

[image]

## Expected behavior

[image]

## Snippet

```
if bearishImb
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput), border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)))
    if array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bearishImbBox))
   
if array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bearishImbBox) -1
        if i <= array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            // delete Box        
            if  t <= high
                box.delete(array.remove(bearishImbBox, i))
            // update Box
            else if b <= high
                box.set_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), high)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing boxes into the array with a right side of the current time of the candle. That's why they're so short. While looping over your boxes, you must update the box and set the right side to the current time of the candle that's processing at that moment. Also, for performance reasons, you might consider doing that only on `barstate.islast`

```
//@version=5
if bearishImb
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput), border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)))
    if array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bearishImbBox))
   
if barstate.islast and array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bearishImbBox) -1
        if i <= array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            box.set_right(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), time) // this was added
            // delete Box        
            if  t <= high
                box.delete(array.remove(bearishImbBox, i))
            // update Box
            else if b <= high
                box.set_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), high)
```

Performance optimization

```
//@version=5
if bearishImb
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput), border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)))
    if array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bearishImbBox))

var box myBox = na

if barstate.islast
    arraySize = array.size(bearishImbBox)
    if arraySize > 0
        for i = 0 to arraySize-1
            if i <= arraySize-1 and arraySize > 0
                myBox := array.get(bearishImbBox, i)
                t = box.get_top(myBox)
                b = box.get_bottom(myBox)
                box.set_right(myBox, time) // this was added
                // delete Box        
                if  t <= high
                    box.delete(array.remove(bearishImbBox, i))
                // update Box
                else if b <= high
                    box.set_bottom(myBox, high)
```

Max number of boxes on screen cannot exceed `numberOfZonesInput`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Imb", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500, max_bars_back = 500)

// ———————————————————— Constants {
// ————— Colors
var color GREEN         = color.green
var color RED           = color.red
var color BLUE          = color.blue
var color YELLOW        = color.yellow

// ————— Constants used in inputs
var string G1 = "Show"
var string G2 = "Hide"

var string IMB1 = "Shrink when mitigated"
var string IMB2 = "Do not shrink"
// }

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
// ————— Imbalance Zones
var GRP3 = "Imbalance Zones"
bool showImbalance = input.bool(true, "Show Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps", inline = "30", group = GRP3)
int numberOfZonesInput = input.int(10, "# Zones", inline = "31", group = GRP3)
bool updateZonesWithPriceMovement = input.string(IMB1, "", inline = "32", options = [IMB1, IMB2], group = GRP3) == IMB1
color bullishImbColorInput = input.color(GREEN, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
color bearishImbColorInput = input.color(RED, "", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
int imbTranspInput = input.int(80, "Transparency", inline = "32", group = GRP3)
// }

// ———————————————————— Imbalance/Fair Value Gaps {
var line bullishImbOpen = na
var line bullishImbLow = na

var line bearishImbOpen = na
var line bearishImbHigh = na

bullishImb = low > high[2]
bearishImb = high < low[2]

var box[] bullishImbBox = array.new_box()
var box[] bearishImbBox = array.new_box()

var color bullColor = color.new(bullishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
var color bearColor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)

if bullishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bullishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low, right = time, bottom = high[2], extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bullColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bullColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bullishImbBox))

if bearishImb and showImbalance
    array.push(bearishImbBox, box.new(left = time[1], top = low[2], right = time, bottom = high, extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, border_color = bearColor, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = bearColor))
    if array.size(bullishImbBox) + array.size(bearishImbBox) > numberOfZonesInput
        box.delete(array.shift(bearishImbBox))

if array.size(bullishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bullishImbBox) - 1
        if i <= array.size(bullishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bullishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bullishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bullishImbBox, i))
            
            // update right side of the box
            box.set_right(array.get(bullishImbBox, i), time)
            
            if updateZonesWithPriceMovement
                // delete box
                if b >= low
                    box.delete(array.remove(bullishImbBox, i))
                // update box
                else if t >= low
                    box.set_top(array.get(bullishImbBox, i), low)


if array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1
        if i <= array.size(bearishImbBox) - 1 and array.size(bearishImbBox) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i))
            
            // update right side of the box
            box.set_right(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), time)
            
            if updateZonesWithPriceMovement
                // delete box        
                if t <= high
                    box.delete(array.remove(bearishImbBox, i))
                // update box
                else if b <= high
                    box.set_bottom(array.get(bearishImbBox, i), high)
// }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you add the `barstate.islast` to the answer too?

Comment: I've added the `barstate.islast` condition to your `if` statement in the code.

Comment: Added performance optimization to the answer. There's no need to do multiple `array.size()` and `array.get()` calls in the loop.

Comment: For some reason, `barstate.islast` changes the zones, they are a bit different than what they should be

Comment: Difficult to assess without the complete script.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/tRuDkg69. When you also select `Do not shrink` from the inputs, it displays more than 10 zones for some reason, instead of just 10. I think something is wrong with the loops.

Comment: Which ticker/timeframe should I run this on?

Comment: Doesnt matter. H4 is okay

Comment: Current behavior https://www.tradingview.com/x/JjDwaA9W/           Expected behavior: https://www.tradingview.com/x/Hzu7Apq4/ (that's with "Do not shrink" option selected in inputs)

Comment: Oh I see, it is showing 10 bullish imbalances and 10 bearish imbalances, instead of just 10 from both types. The other option (Shrink when mitigated) works as intended.

Comment: Your code is correct. You shouldn't use `barstate.islast` as I mentioned, because you delete boxes as you go, and not just only on the last bar. One little last tip maybe, is that you could define your colors on beforehand, instead of generating a new one for each box you create. Like this : `var color bullColor = color.new(bullishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
var color bearColor = color.new(bearishImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
`

Comment: Thank you! What about the amount of the zones when "Do not shrink" option is selected? It selects 10 zones of bullish and bearish types because they are two arrays, instead of 10 elements from both types.

Comment: Added code for Max number of boxes on screen cannot exceed numberOfZonesInput

Comment: It is better, but there is something wrong, because look at that. Current behavior: https://www.tradingview.com/x/HwhKgX9G/. Expected behavior: https://www.tradingview.com/x/Oej6L2Dz/. That's BINANCE:CRVUSDT Daily tf. Notice the green zones that it missed (btw "Do not shrink" option). The current behavior basically missed the green ones for some reason and showed red ones that are more in the past.

Comment: I don't see how that can be done. Sorry.